# Failed to run julia studio

Tags: julia

I tried to run [Julia Studio](http://forio.com/julia/tutorials/advanced/tutorial1.html) before running [Julia](http://julialang.org/downloads/) and it was working. However, once I ran Julia and then started running Julia Studio, I keep getting `JuliaStudio.exe has stopped working`. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the studio but was not successful. I am currently using Vista 32 bit,JuliaStudio-0.3.1, and Julia v0.1.2. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going into `C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Roaming` and deleting / moving the folder called `JuliaStudio`. Note that the "AppData" folder is hidden, so you might not see it in explorer. You can show hidden files and folders by going to `Control Panel->Appearance and Personalization->Show hidden files and folders`.

Hope this helps. Sometimes Julia Studio's config files get corrupted, there is an issue filed here: https://github.com/forio/julia-studio/issues/124

Comment: Perfect. It worked now. Can you please tell me why JuliaStudio folder in the `C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Roaming` path is generating an error?

Comment: Now I have another issue :`"Preparing Julia for first launch. This may take a while" 
"You may see two git related errors. This is completely normal" 
The system cannot find the path specified.
'"julia-release-basic.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`
After that I can't do anything. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: I haven't debugged the config crash yet, I'm not sure what's wrong.

As for this new problem, it looks like Julia Studio can't find your copy of Julia. You can point it at different versions using `Tools->Options->Julia->Path to binaries`. The ide comes with a version, you can point at the folder called "julia" in the root dir of your Julia Studio install. Let me know if that doesn't work.